# Generalize tournament/championship "capacity"?

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I describe tournament/championship "capacity" in one ***word***?
Like "tournament ***word*** is 10 players max" or "championship ***word*** is 5 teams max" or even "game ***word*** is 5 teams max".

Can I actually use "capacity" for this?

Comment: Welcome. Use "limit" for both players and teams in your examples.

Answer (score 2):

Except for *game*, I don't think you need a word there.

> Tournament is 10 players max(imum).
>
> Championship is 10 players max(imum).

Both read fine to me. I think (max) implies a sense of capacity or limit.

Comment: To me, that sounds rather inarticulate.